# why list1.removeAll(list2) remove all the duplicates elements not the number of occurrence in list2

Tags: java, list, removeall

I have created two ArrayList of Integer. List1 contains [1, 2, 2, 2, 5] and List2 contains [2]. I tried List1.removeAll(List2) should remove 2 from List1 only once instead its removing all occurrences of 2 from List1.
Also the List1.remove(List2) doesn't work at all.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
        list1.add(2);
        list1.add(5);
        list1.add(1);
        list1.add(2);
        list1.add(2);
        Collections.sort(list1);
        System.out.println(list1);
        ArrayList<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
        list2.add(2);
        list1.removeAll(list2);
        System.out.println(list1);
}

Expected OUTPUT - [1, 2, 2, 2, 5]
                  [1, 2, 2, 5]

Actual OUTPUT - [1, 2, 2, 2, 5]
                [1, 5]
```

Comment: _should remove 2 from List1 only once instead its removing all occurrences_ According to who or what?

Comment: Because that's what it's supposed to do, according to its specifications, that you can read in the javadoc.

Comment: FYI here's the documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#removeAll-java.util.Collection-

Answer (score 2):

> I tried List1.removeAll(List2) should remove 2 from List1 only once instead its removing all occurrences of 2 from List1

No. List1.removeAll(List2) removes all occurrences of List2(from List1) because that's what it's [documented](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#removeAll-java.util.Collection-) to do:

> boolean removeAll(Collection c)
>
> Removes from this list all of its elements that are contained in the specified collection (optional operation).

If you want to remove only the first element, you are supposed to use [List.remove(object)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove-java.lang.Object-). Following is the ref from doc:

> boolean remove(Object o)
>
> Removes the first occurrence of the specified element from this list, if it is present (optional operation). If this list does not contain the element, it is unchanged.

Comment: @MunauwarShaikh Please accept the answer if it answers your question. :)

Answer (score 1):

You need [`List.remove(Object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove-java.lang.Object-) if you want to remove the *first* match (as noted in the linked Javadoc). [`List.removeAll(Collection<?>)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#removeAll-java.util.Collection-) removes all of the matches. You can also use `IntStream` to construct your `List`(s), and use `List` (instead of the **specific** `ArrayList` implementation). Like,

```
List<Integer> list1 = IntStream.of(2, 5, 1, 2, 2).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
Collections.sort(list1);
System.out.println(list1);
List<Integer> list2 = IntStream.of(2).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
for (Integer v : list2) {
    list1.remove(v);
}
System.out.println(list1);
```

Which outputs

```
[1, 2, 2, 2, 5]
[1, 2, 2, 5]
```

Comment: is there any other way to do this. if I don't want use for each loop on list2 ?